# FirebaseSerializer for authentication messing with my models

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I'm in the process of implementing Facebook Authentication via Ember CLI + Emberfire + Firebase.

My FirebaseSerializer is messing up the entire app right now.

Here's the error I got:

> Error while processing route: lists.index
>
> Assertion Failed: A (subclass of DS.Model) record was pushed into the store with the value of todos being '{-JnTd8HfiWnSCMri7zHV: true}', but todos is a hasMany relationship so the value must be an array. You should probably check your data payload or serializer. Error: Assertion Failed: A (subclass of DS.Model) record was pushed into the store with the value of todos being '{-JnTd8HfiWnSCMri7zHV: true}', but todos is a hasMany relationship so the value must be an array. You should probably check your data payload or serializer.

If I click on the debug link, I see:

> Ember['default'].Logger.error.apply(this, errorArgs);

Here is my serializer saved under nutella/serializers/app.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import FirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/adapters/firebase';

export default DS.FirebaseSerializer.extend();
```

And here's part the code I added for OAuth that may be causing a problem:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var session = Ember.Object.extend({
    ref : new Firebase("https://nutella.firebaseio.com"),

    addFirebaseCallback: function() {
        var session = this;

        this.get("ref").onAuth(function(authData) {
            if (authData) {
                session.set("isAuthenticated", true);
            } else {
                session.set("isAuthenticated", false);
            }
        });
    }.on("init"),

    login: function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            this.get("ref").authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, user) {
                if (user) {
                    resolve(user);
                } else {
                    reject(error);
                }
            });
        });
    },

    currentUser: function() {
        return this.get("ref").getAuth();
    }.property("isAuthenticated")
});


export default {
    name: "Session",

    initialize: function (container, app) {
        app.register("session:main", session);
        app.inject("controller", "session", "session:main");
        app.inject("route", "session", "session:main");
    }
};
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Which versions of Ember CLI, EmberFire and Ember are you using?

Comment: I'm using "ember-cli": "0.2.3",  "emberfire": "^1.4.4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up the application serializer you should be creating a file at `app/serializers/application.js` (not `app.js`). Your app is actually falling back to the default Ember Data serializer.

Here is the correct code for setting up FirebaseSerializer as the app's default:

```
// app/serializers/application.js
import FirebaseSerializer from 'emberfire/serializers/firebase';

export default FirebaseSerializer.extend();
```

However this is probably not necessary.

To get emberfire working you need to use the Firebase **adapter**. When you activate this adapter it will *automatically* register the Firebase serializer as the application default (you can delete `app/serializers/application.js` completely).

Are you declaring the firebase adapter in `app/adapters/application.js`? If not, the quickest way to do this is to run the emberfire generator again:

```
ember generate emberfire
```

This will create your `app/adapters/application.js`:

```
import config from '../config/environment';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import FirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/adapters/firebase';

export default FirebaseAdapter.extend({
  firebase: new Firebase(config.firebase)
});
```

It will place an example firebase URL in `config/environment.js`. Update this to your real URL.

These initial steps are outlined in the [emberfire quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ember/quickstart.html) docs.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you so much. You saved my life. I had 'import ds from ember-data' instead of import FirebaseSerializer from 'emberfire/serializers/firebase'; and that messed it up.